# Rails generate figaro:install is not generating .yml file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, rubygems

I've just started on the book Learn Ruby on Rails. On the configuration file chapter it states running "rails generate figaro:install" should generate a config/application.yml file. I ran it and kept getting an error. There was a gem I had trouble installing which was gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' and the only one available alternative was gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.3". I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the fact that I keep getting this error. I also posted at the bottom what I get when I try to run this command.

```
    /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/compass-rails-1.1.3/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
from /home/oscar/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
from /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with figaro -- it appears to be related to the newer version of the sass gem, which is included as a dependency of compass. I fixed by adding the following to my gemfile, per [this suggestion](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1339#issuecomment-21354760) (newer releases of sass may work, too).

`gem 'sass', '3.3.0.alpha.149'`

You'll probably need to run `bundle update sass` from the command line as well. Hope that helps!